# I think there is something wrong with my code?

Tags: laravel

I'm not really sure how to word this question, but I really hope that you can help. I made a search engine it has two inputs one for what you want to search for and one for the city and state pretty awesome little project. I'm trying to use str_replace() for the city and state. However, the user may input the city and state whether it be with a comma or no comma or spaced or doubled spaced it will find the result hence the reason why I'm using str_replace but only the $strr variable is Effective, and the other variables are not working

This is what I have

```
$userinput=$request->input('$what');
$city&state=$request->input('$where');

$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $userinput));
$sty = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $userinput));

$strr=str_replace(", ", ",", $city&state);
$strrr=str_replace(", ", ",", $city&state);
$strrrr=str_replace(" ,", " ," ," ,", $city&state);
$stq=str_replace(",", " ", $city&state);   
$stw=str_replace(",", " ", $city&state);

$pro=User::where('tags','Like','%'. $str .'%')
        ->where(function ($query) use($strrr,$strr,$strrrr,$stq,$stw) {
            $query->where('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strr .'%')
                ->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strrr .'%')
                ->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strrrr .'%')
                ->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $stq .'%')
                ->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $stw .'%');

        })
        ->orWhere('company_name','Like','%'. $str .'%')
        ->where(function ($query) use($strrr,$strr,$strrrr) {
            $query->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strr .'%')
                ->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strrr .'%')
                ->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strrrr .'%');
        })
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: This isn't clear what you are asking and the formatting makes it harder to understand.

Comment: @Luke I edited my question, is the question clear enough?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal, complete, example of your problem? You have got a lot of code there: try to pare it down. (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help)

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf sorry for all the code I edited it. Is it clear?

Comment: Why don't you make a single search term, and just clean your input using a function?

What format do you want the search term in and maybe we can help then

Comment: it dose not really have to be in a format I just want it to match the city and state no matter what format they may type it in. Like when you use indeed.com for instance and you type in what you want and the where no matter how you type the city and state like Miami, fl or miami fl it sill shows accurate results

Comment: Rename your question to an actual question please.

Comment: What do you mean by the other variables are "not working"? What's happening? Also, `&` is not a valid character in a variable name. In PHP a variable must start with `$` and may only contain letters, numbers and underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than do multiple `str_replace`'s I'd suggest a single function that cleans the inputs, as a general example the below code will remove any leading / trailing or double spaces and commas and replace with a single space.

```
function clean_input($str) {
     return preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', ' ', trim($str));
}

$searches = ['City, State', 'City State', 'City , State', 'City  State', ' City  state '];

foreach ($searches as $search) {
    print cleanInput($search) . PHP_EOL;
}

// Prints.

City State
City State
City State
City State
City state
```